# Disable other option in same div, when first one is selected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable all options in the same div as soon as one is selected. I'm stuck.

Tried to use onchange. But whenever I try to disable the selects, it's either all or none and not within the same parent element (like div or table row)

```
<div>

1: <select class="first">
<optgroup label="Div 1, select 1">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="1-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="1-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br />
2: <select class="second">
<optgroup label="Div 1, select 2">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="1-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="1-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
<div>
1: <select class="first">
<optgroup label="Div 2, select 1">

  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="2-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="2-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br />
2: <select class="second">
<optgroup label="Div 2, select 2">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="2-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="2-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>


$('div option:selected').closest(select).attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Szenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/1keyup/no8abt0m/11/

Thank you very much in advnace

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to handle the main divs individually.

```js
$('.item1-first-div').on('change', function() {
  var value = $('.item1-first-div').val();
  if (value) {
    $('.item2-first-div').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.item2-first-div').prop('disabled', false);
  }

});

$('.item1-second-div').on('change', function() {
  var value = $('.item1-second-div').val();
  if (value) {
    $('.item2-second-div').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.item2-second-div').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px
}

select {
  padding: 5px 7px;
}

.first {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  1: <select class="first item1-first-div">
<optgroup label="Div 1, select 1">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option>1.1</option>
  <option>1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br /> 2: <select class="second item2-first-div">
<optgroup label="Div 1, select 2">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option>1.1</option>
  <option>1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  1: <select class="first item1-second-div">
<optgroup label="Div 2, select 1">

  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="1-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="1-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select><br /> 2: <select class="second item2-second-div">
<optgroup label="Div 2, select 2">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="2-1">1.1</option>
  <option value="2-2">1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, this is actually really helpful. and it's working without specifically refering to the div itself. Just looking for a way to enable it again, once i select the empty value

Comment: hi, sorry, for answering here. I'm unable to do so in the chat:

as it is now, the second select get's disabled. But if I choose the empty value again, I'd like to get the second one enabled agian.

Comment: made a change in JS, now it will allow you to re-enable when you select ...

Comment: this thing is trickier as it first seems. disabling should only affect every select within the same div.

Comment: Is this not the current behavior? Am I missing something?

Comment: no, I choose the first select option, both of the second selects get disabled.

Comment: colored the disabled, so it's easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/1keyup/no8abt0m/25/

Comment: You have made an error in your JS first line $('.first').on('change', function() { .... Mine is $('.item1-first-div').on('change', function() {